# Display limited number of characters for foreign language in Laravel

Tags: php, string, laravel, laravel-blade

If we want to show limited number of english character in laravel blade we use

`{!! str_limit($data->details, 100) !!}`

But if I want to show limited number foreign character (i.e: bangla) in laravel what should I use?

I have used  `{!! str_limit($data->details, 100) !!}` but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

str_limit is [deprecated](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26898) from 5.8. Instead you have to use [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-str-limit) functions provided by laravel.

I tried the following code in my machine and it worked.

```
{{ Str::limit('ও মন রমজানের ঐ রোজার শেষে এলো খুশির ঈদ', 10) }}
```

Comment: anything need to add in helper ? or just replace `str_limit` with `Str::limit` will work ?
I replaced but not working

Comment: You don't need to add anything when using in blade. Just replacing should work. However, in case of using it in controller you need to import "Illuminate\Support\Str"

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: using version 5.8... And applied the code in blade.